# CentOS 6でsvnおよびgitのバージョンを上げた際のgit-svnの問題

Tags: git, centos, svn

CentOS 6のsvnとgitのバージョンを上げた際のgit-svnの問題についてです。

CentOS 6のyumで入るsubversionは1.6系なので、これを下記のサイトの方法で1.8系にアップデート:
[CentOS 6でsubversionのバージョンを上げる](http://www.torutk.com/projects/swe/wiki/CentOS_6%E3%81%A7subversion%E3%81%AE%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%82%92%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B)

同じくCentOS 6のyumで入るgitも古いので下記のサイトの方法でアップデート
(そのままやるとこけるのでsubversion-perlをwandisco-svnからインストールしてからgitをインストールします):
[CentOS 6でgitのバージョンを上げる](http://www.torutk.com/projects/swe/wiki/CentOS_6%E3%81%A7git%E3%81%AE%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%82%92%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B)

両方ともwandiscoのRPMを使用する方法です。
上記方法と同様にしてgit-svnもインストール

```
yum install --enablerepo=wandisco-git --disablerepo=base,updates,epel git-svn
```

ところがこの方法で導入したgit-svnによるチェックアウトが失敗してしまいます。

```
git svn clone https://exapmle.com/repos ./
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/user/test/.git/
不正な URL が RA 層に渡されました: 'https://exapmle.com/repos' 用の URL スキームを認識できません at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Git/SVN.pm line 148
```

Answer (score 1):

CentOS のパッケージに詳しくないので、綺麗な（パッケージのインストールだけで）方法がちょっとわからないのですが、[本家SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13865154/4037) で似た質問がありました。

まず、`svn --version` と打ち込み、`- handles 'https' scheme` という行が表示されるか確認します。これで、インストールした svn に https 機能があるか確認できます。

インストール方法から類推するに HTTPS 機能はあると思います。

その場合、git-svn が古い svn を使っている可能性があります。
原因として挙げられているのは

1. SVN に Perl のバインディングが入っていない可能性があります。入っていないと、http(s) 機能がないデフォルトバイナリを使ってしまうようです。
2. Perl モジュールの設定でで `PATH/LD_LIBRARY_PATH` か `PERL5LIB` が設定できておらず、git-svn が上と同じようにデフォルトバイナリを使ってしまっている。

[この方](http://yano3.hatenablog.jp/entry/2013/01/30/194506)は 1.7 系ですが、自分でコンパイルする際に neon-devel がないと同じエラーになったようです。ご自身でコンパイルすることにした場合は参考になると思います。

ちょっとはっきりした答えにならず、申し訳ないです。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。おっしゃる通りsvn --versionで見た限りではhttpsはserfがハンドルしているはずなので、git-svnの参照先が変なのだとは思うのですが。